# Can this ruby (rails) method be tidied up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm fairly new to ruby (and am using Rails) and was wondering whether the following method could be tidied up. In its current state it does work, however I get the feeling that there is a much nicer way of writing it and would like to learn more about the syntax.

```
def fullAddress
  full = self.address1 + "</br>"
  if self.address2.blank?
  else
    full = full + self.address2  + "</br>"
  end
  if self.address3.blank?
  else
    full = full + self.address3  + "</br>"
  end
  full = full + self.posttown + "</br>" + self.postcode
end
```

Every 'self' will have address1, posttown and postcode, but address2 and address3 are optional and should only be added to the fullAddress if they are present (i.e. neither nil or blank).

This question might not be suitable for SO, but I've come across this type of helper method quite a bit and am sure I can implement it in a nicer way.

Comment: if you only have code for the else block you should negate with `if !condition` or the equivalent `unless condition`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
def full_address
  [address1, address2, address3, posttown, postcode].reject{|l| l.blank?}.join('</br>')
end
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know reject before (contrary of select).

Comment: But that differs too much from the original in sematics, depending on data state, one can end up with a whole different result.

Comment: or reject(&:blank?) or select(&:present?). Or join(tag(:br))

Comment: Nice answer yep. But I agree with @clyfe.

Comment: oh, and in 1.9.2 or ActiveResource loaded one can `x.reject(&:blank?)`

Comment: @clyfe: It's in 1.8.7+ or with `ActiveSupport` or `backports` loaded that one can use `x.reject(&:some_method)`. But `blank?` is defined in `ActiveSupport`, so you can always replace `reject{|l| l.blank?}` with `x.reject(&:blank?)` :-)

Comment: meant ActiveSupport not ActiveResource sorry

Answer (score 5):

My take:

```
def fullAddress
  full = [address1]
  full << address2 unless address2.blank?
  full << address3 unless address3.blank?
  full << posttown << postcode
  full.join "</br>"
end
```

`self` is implicit in method calls, and a bit of juggling with arrays.

Comment: nice thing is that yours needs only one array

Answer (score 1):

```
def fullAddress
  full = address1 + "<br>"
  full += address2 + "<br>" unless address2.blank?
  full += address3 + "<br>" unless address3.blank?
  full += posttown + "<br>" + postcode
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This does *exactly* the same as your code:

```
def full_adress
  ([address1] +
   [address2, address3].reject(&:blank?) +
   [posttown, postcode]
  ).join("<br/>")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
def full_address
  [address1,
   address2,
   address3,
   posttown,
   postcode].inject("") do |full_addr, line|
     full_addr << line + '<br/>' unless line.blank?
     full_addr
   end.chomp('</br>')
end
```

It needs just one array, and starts constructing the string immediately. It should work fine for short strings (and full addresses are short strings).